# Implement object.prototype.function in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have below Javascript code in which I am creating an object as **new Box2** and inserting each object into an array .Inside loop I am calling draw() on each element. Everything works good in plain js but I want to implement this code in ionic 3. If the same code is copied in .ts file in Ionic , in editor it gives **error as** :
[ts] Duplicate identifier 'Box2'.
[ts] Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'Box2' must be of type '() => void', but here has type 'any'.  while in browser it gives error as ';' expected for line Box2.prototype

```
Box2() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.w = 1; // default width and height?
    this.h = 1;
    this.fill = '#444444';
  }

  Box2.prototype = {
    draw : function(){
      console.log("hello");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to extend prototype in typescript with interface. Like this:

```js
class Box2 {
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  w = 1; // default width and height?
  h = 1;
  fill = '#444444';
}

interface Box2 { // this interface will allow us to implement draw
  draw(): void;
}

Box2.prototype.draw = function() {
  console.log("hello");
}

// usage of our draw function
new Box2().draw();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got this working by creating another file with class Box2 and implemented the draw() in that class. I have imported the file where i want to use it and created the Box2 object.

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to share your solution by editing your post (and to upvote my post if it help in anyway ;) )